# C++20 standard library on Android? std::source_location support

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, clang, c++20

I have an issue with [Android support in log4cplus](https://github.com/wilx/log4cplus/actions/runs/4213340922/jobs/7312988167). I can use `std::source_location` in MSVC and in both GCC and Clang on Ubuntu. But the Android NDK, while it uses Clang 14, seems to lack that. Is there some variable I can use to enable it or C++20 conforming standard C++ library in CMake Android build? See https://github.com/wilx/log4cplus/actions/runs/4213340922/workflow for the GitHub action descriptor.

Comment: You can test for it being supported with the `__cpp_lib_source_location` [feature test](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test).

Comment: BTW, latest Xcode 14.2 on mac still doesn't support `std::source_location` neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libc++ only supports `std::source_location` starting with LLVM/Clang version 16, see https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx20.html, which as far as I can tell means that at the moment no Android NDK supports it.

On Ubuntu you are probably using libstdc++ with Clang, which is a separate implementation of the standard library (part of GCC).